# Array in Database not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :title, :details, :user_id
    serialize :volunteers,Array
end
```

TasksController

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @task = Task.new
    end

    def create
        @task = Task.new(params[:task])
        @task.user_id = current_user.id
        if @task.save
            flash[:notice] = "Task successfully added"
            redirect_to static_pages_dashboard_path
         end
     end 

     def show
         @task = Task.find(params[:id])
     end

     def index
        @task = Task.all
     end

     def update
        @task = Task.find(params[:id])
        @task.volunteers << profile_path(current_user.profile)
        if @task.save
            flash[:notice] = "You have accepted the task"
        end
     end
end
```

tasks/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Task Summary</h1>
<%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
Title: <%=@task.title%> <br/>
Details: <%=@task.details%> <br/>
Requested by: <%=@task.user_id%> <br/>

<%= link_to "Accept Task", tasks_path(current_user.profile) %>
```

routes.rb

```
Test::Application.routes.draw do
   get "welcome/index"
   get "static_pages/home"
   get "static_pages/dashboard"
   get "tasks/index"
   root "static_pages#home"
   devise_for :users 
   resources :tasks
   resources :profiles
end
```

Hi. I am attempting to update the array `volunteers` in the model by appending the `user_id` of `current_user` to the array. However when I test it and click "Accept Task", which links to the `update` action, nothing happens. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Accept Task" link will not link to the `update` action, since you aren't specifying to use the 'PUT' method.  It will instead link to the 'show' action.

Moreover, you are passing `current_user.profile` to the `tasks_path` helper - this is not going to get you the correct RESTful address.  Change your link to look like this:

```
<%= link_to "Accept Task", task_path(@task), :method => :put %>
```

Or even simpler:

```
<%= link_to "Accept Task", @task, :method => :put %>
```